# Asking for reservation process

Tags: php, mysql, html, codeigniter

I am currently making a website which includes reservation system.. I want to ask if how can I avoid multiple reservation (I mean prank reservation). I want it like this, if someone made a reservation, the system will not add it in the database right away.. It must get a confirmation from the user if he/she is really sure of the reservation he made.. If the user confirms then that's the time, it will be added in the database.. How can I do this? Can anyone help me?

Comment: Add it in straight away, but with a flag that gets set from 0 to 1 once the reservation is confirmed.

Comment: @ Sepehr Farshid , what I have is a reservation that automatically add the information of the user who made a reservation in the database.. The issue here is that, what if a certain user made a prank reservation multiple times? Then the database will be full of fake reservations/reservation that isn't really sure..

Comment: @Strawberry, but it will still be added to database right away? What you mean is I will just have to add a certain field with datatype boolean in my `reservation` table?

Comment: Boolean or tinyint - either's fine. A PK or UNIQUE key should prevent a user submitting multiple reservations for the same date.

Comment: This is not just a do this or that question.. you need to provide your current code.. like, how are you currently processing each request? how are you currently storing it in the database? once we know how your current code is structured we can then implement ways of doing what you desire. A flag ( as Strawberry mentioned) is definitely something i would consider, but again, it depends on the structure or approach you currently have.

Comment: Ok, I get it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the comments I reckon best bet is to create your booking entry and add a flag to indicate that the booking entry is unconfirmed. Then it would make sense to send confirmation e-mail with a link to redirect the user to a php script which would flag the booking as confirmed. This is pretty standard stuff you should find examples to follow for how to construct a one time confirmation URL

There is mention in the comments about how to avoid multiple bookings. Rather than look at primary keys/unique constraints  this would be more simply achieved by checking the users e-mail address and ensuring its unique to that date and time. A unique constraint on the email wouldnt make sense as presumably you would wish for the same user to make more than one booking. You could consider a composite constraint on date and email but this would probably be too rigid at db level. Better to implement in PHP with a configurable value (eg no email can book more than once per X hours/days)

Post your code for more input

Answer (score 0):

have one db table for the temporary reservations, and another db table for the confirmed reservations. when the customer confirms the reservation a record is created in the confirmed reservations table. this also keeps things separate for the website and the admin tools: the customers are accessing the temporary reservations db table -- the admins are accessing the confirmed reservations table.

otherwise you have a db table that is a mishmash of real reservations and uncompleted ones. to verify a user first step would be searching on the email address being unique. second would be sending an email to user and they have to click and respond to it -- so you confirm they are entering an email address they have access to. third would be requiring a mobile phone number -- validating the number being unique -- then sending the user a text message with a random string that they have to enter in the website to confirm the reservation.

Comment: Well, it's not how I'd do it.

Comment: Yeah causing yourself a headache with second table. There is no need its a waste of time and effort to maintain. Just a simple status flag to describe the state eg 'unconfirmed','confirmed','cancelled' etc

Comment: the first table has no value. the second table IS the business value. the first table is publicly exposed. the second table with the business assets is always private. noting that part of his problem is users hitting the reservation table with multiple submissions.